# Retrieve two SQL date columns using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

Good day, I have this javascript where it deducts two dates to get a timer for a feature in my website where individual cards have their own countdowns based on time claimed. the countdown is always exactly 48 hours from the time clicked.

I reverted my javascript as it only shows errors (on line 12...etc). right now the js is only getting the current date and adding 48 hours for the timer. How do I get the sql column into my javascript?

Javascript:

```
var countdown_48 = new Date; countdown_48.setHours( countdown_48.getHours() + 48 );

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countdown_48 - now;
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.querySelectorAll('.c_countdown').forEach(function(elem){
    elem.innerHTML = innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  })

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("c_countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

- my target is to get the sql columns shown below (createddate & expirationdate) into "var countdown_48"

SQL: (order)

[image: sql]

Here are my other connections with php:

list-claimed.php

```
    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Reclaim This Coupon In:<hr></td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <td class="c_countdown"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

- this is the table where the countdown is displayed
- list-claimed.php is connected to a vc.php file to connect to the database using "require_once('list-claimed.vc.php');"

list-claimed.vc.php

- table order where the two dates are taken are connected with:

  require_once($routePath . "_mc/Order.mc.php");
    $mcOrder = new Order_MC();

  $orderid = $rowOrder['orderid'];
    $rowOrder = $mcOrder->SelectObj_ByUsrCustomer_Claimed($db, $productid, $usrcustomerid);

Order.mc.php

```
  public function SelectLst_ByUsrCustomerID($db, $pageNum, $limit, $usrcustomerid) {
    $start = ($pageNum * $limit) - $limit;

$stmt = $db->prepare(
  " SELECT orderid, productid, usrcustomerid, amount, amountrefunded, createddate, scheduleddate, useddate, expirationdate
    FROM `order`
    WHERE usrcustomerid = :usrcustomerid
    ORDER BY createddate DESC
    LIMIT " . $start . ", " . $limit
);

$stmt->bindValue(':usrcustomerid', $usrcustomerid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $rows;
```

}

- here is the output (each card should have its own timer based on the createddate and expirationdate)

[image: cards]